# Select Non-Adjacent Files on MacOS Using Only the Keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a technology instructor for the visually impaired.  On Windows, I'm able to select non-adjacent files using the keyboard by pressing control + up/down arrow keys to get to the next desired file and pressing space to select the next file, rinse and repeat.  How do I do this in MacOS?

I know I can select one right after the other with shift + arrow keys, but I need to know for files that are not right after the other.

I also know that you can "command + click" to select files that are not near each other in the list, but as I said, I'm a technology instructor for the visually impaired; many of my students cannot see the mouse.

Comment: Maybe [apple.se] would be a better place to ask a Mac-specific question like this.